# Is it possible to update an existing data extension row with Custom Activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Hi I have a custom activity where in upon execute it will call a webservice. I'm good up to this point also I'm able to get the response, now the question is

Using the response that I received is it possible to update the row of a certain data extension?

Thank you.

This is a sample of my custom activity, activity.js

exports.execute = function (req, res) {
    //console.log("execute function!!!");

```
console.log("EXECUTE HAS BEEN RUN");
JWT(req.body, process.env.JWT_KEY, (err, decoded) => {

    // verification error -> unauthorized request
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(401).end();
    }


    if (decoded && decoded.inArguments && decoded.inArguments.length > 0) {[]

    //Use fields in decoded.inarguments to create a request body
    //use node.js to do webservice
    var bodyStringAdvertising = JSON.stringify({
    //Sample body
    })

    var headersAdvertising = {
    //Sample header
    }

    var optionsAdvertising = { 
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headersAdvertising,
    url: '//Sample URL'
    };

    request(optionsAdvertising, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log('response body',body);

    //Once I get the response, I'm going to use some of the values to update 
    a row in a Data Extension
    //How Can I do that

    }).write(bodyStringAdvertising); 

    } else {
        console.error('inArguments invalid.');
        return res.status(400).end();
    }

});

console.log("end execute function!!!");
```

};

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, you have to use marketing cloud API you can use REST API or SOAP API it depends on you, ie REST API: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.htm
The same applies to SOAP API, you can find many examples in this page.